# In monocle js library want to load the HTML page in a single iframe

Tags: javascript, width, device

Currently I am using Monocle javascript library in my project. The monocle library will load the HTML files in iframes. It uses the device width and height to crop the HTML contents and create pages based on these measurements. 
I need to disable this property. I would like to display a single HTML file in a single iframe  . That is, it should be the same as it was in the epub file. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use http://sourceforge.net/projects/oplsepublibrary/ php epub reader to write the content of epub to a page